# SparkStatementException: "Reference is ambiguous

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running the following query in spark.sql:

```
%%time
%%spark
spark.sql('''select
dt_mvtc,
cd_cli,
cd_gr_mdld_prd_pd,
anot_pda_cli,
MAX(case when TMP_QUALI = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DEF_QUALI,
MAX(case when anot_pda_cli = 1 or (ANOT_PDA_PRD = 1 and MAX_VLR_PDA > 100) then 1 else 0 end) AS CD_DSCP_PRJZ_BCO
from temp_safras_qlt_aux
group by dt_mvtc, cd_cli, cd_gr_mdld_prd_pd
''')
```

But I am keep on getting this error: `SparkStatementException: "Reference 'anot_pda_cli' is ambiguous, could be: temp_safras_qlt_aux.anot_pda_cli, temp_safras_qlt_aux.anot_pda_cli.`
Even tough I put `temp_safras_qlt_aux.anot_pda_cli` in my query, the error persists. I have dealt with such an error before, but now from my understanding it is telling me that is ambiguous and I choose from A or A (?????). It is saying the ambiguity could be solved by choosing between A or A and if I choose A the error is EXACTLY the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe `temp_safras_qlt_aux` is the temp view created by another dataframe or that have same column?

Comment: I find this message confusing, too. Isn't it rather that you should not be able to select `anot_pda_cli` at all, because you group by `dt_mvtc, cd_cli, cd_gr_mdld_prd_pd`? Wouldn't you have to say *which* of the group's `anot_pda_cli` you want to select (e.g. `MIN(anot_pda_cli)`)?

Comment: yes, indeed, `temp_safras_qlt_aux` is a temp view. Is this a problem?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner don't know, I will try that

Comment: @Dimitri, try to rename `anot_pda_cli` to something else, it might conflict with the temp view.